# rxjs share operator with a timed cache

Tags: rxjs, rxjs7

I'm trying to implement a caching HTTP network call that dumps the result from the cache after a specific amount of time, so I implemented this operator:

```js
export const cacheForMinutes = <T>(minutes?: number) => <T>(source: Observable<T>) => {
    if (!(minutes && minutes > 0))
        return source

    return source.pipe(share<T>({
        connector: () => new ReplaySubject(1),
        resetOnComplete: () => timer(minutes * 60_000)
    }))
}
```

Then in my service, I use it like this:

```js
getDtoSingle(..., minutesToCache: number) {
    return this.http.get(...).pipe(
        map(...),
        cacheForMinutes(minutesToCache)
    )
}
```

When I watch the network calls via Chrome developer tools, I can see that it's not actually caching the results for the given time, it's still making the network call each time.  What have I done wrong here?

Comment: I think it’s not caching because each time your method is called, a new observable is returned. So, consumers of the method are subscribing to different observables. In order for your caching to work, you need multiple subscriptions to the same observable.

Comment: So if I took the `get` output and stored that as a class variable, and then the method call returned that with the `pipe` part, would it work as I'm expecting?

Comment: @BizzyBob Unfortunately my hope didn't work.

Comment: Here's a simple example [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-73197766?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts,item.service.ts) that works.  Maybe this will help.

Comment: @BizzyBob It's the difference between a hot and cold observable.  `of` is cold, and an HTTP call is `hot` (or I got that backward).

Comment: I don't see any problem with your solution. The stream it's shared and also cached (in the network only 1 call it's made, even if the source it's subscribed in the template twice) https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jew1g7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Try forking the StackBlitz sample and replacing with an http call.  I think it would still work.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to cache the result in an external variable as you said, and access it with some deep comparison method (like using `object-hash`) and then remove it when it is done. Example:

```js
import hash from 'object-hash'
const cache: Record<string, Observable<any>> = {}
export function getDtoSingle(query, minutesToCache: number) {
    const q = hash(query)
    return of(0).pipe(swichMap(()=>
      cache[q] ?? (cache[q] = this.http.get(query).pipe(
        finalize(()=>delete cache[q]),
        map(...),
        cacheForMinutes(minutesToCache)
      ))
    ))
}
```

Comment: I know deleting the result after expiration is not mandatory but it is a good practice to not leave any no longer used data in the memory

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about why the hash please?  Also, an HTTP call is normally closed automatically, and so we don't have to unsubscribe from it.  Wouldn't doing a concat with `NEVER` mean that I'd have to start doing so?

Comment: the hash is just to create a unique id for complex queries, and you are right about the complete, I removed it